# How to query multiplte row in one json object

Tags: mysql, sql

table provider

[image]

table provider_properties

[image]

here I wanted the result something like

```
{
  "provider_uuid": "b897f790-ee90-4869-9345-690380b1a0c9",
  "name": "Provider 1",
  "password": "112233",
  "username": "provider_1",
  "properties": {
    "address_1": "Dubai",
    "address_2": "NY"
  }
}
```

here i tried something like

```
SELECT provider.*, json_object(provider_properties.key_name, provider_properties.key_value) as properties FROM provider JOIN provider_properties on provider.provider_id = provider_properties.provider_uuid;
```

but the problem is i am getting 2 rows

[image]

Comment: Build `"properties"` object in aggregated subquery, use JSON_OBJECTAGG().

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since your expected results need specific formatting in json. You want to refer to [JSON Formatted output](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/mysql-shell/8.0/en/mysql-shell-json-output.html). This is for shell though.

You might also want to try this...

This would give you a tabular results but in one row.

```
SELECT 
    provider.*, 
    p_props.properties 
FROM provider 
JOIN (
    provider_uuid,
    SELECT JSON_OBJECTAGG(
        provider_properties.key_name,
        provider_properties.key_value
    ) as properties
    FROM provider_properties 
    GROUP BY provider_uuid
) p_props ON provider.provider_id = p_props.provider_uuid;
```

Comment: Yes it works .
Thanks. 

'provider_uuid' will be added as a column before JSON_OBJECTAGG

Comment: Yes... updated the answer

Answer (score 1):

1. `CONCAT()` and `REPLACE()` here are used for sorting the order of columns.
2. I would say the use of `REPLACE()` here is quite risky, please test it out and see how it goes.

[db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=996d39eed382a371c3545383fc7497ab)

```
SELECT 
    p.*,
    CONCAT(
        '{"', 'provider_uuid": "', pp.provider_uuid, '"',
        REPLACE(JSON_OBJECT('name', p.name, 'password', p.password, 
                            'username', p.username, 'properties', pp.name_value), '{"name', ', "name')
    ) AS your_json
FROM provider p
JOIN (
    SELECT provider_uuid, JSON_OBJECTAGG(key_name, key_value) as name_value
    FROM provider_properties 
    GROUP BY provider_uuid
) pp ON p.provider_id = pp.provider_uuid;
```